OpenCV IMSHOW error when running even when provided all parameters
I am using OpenCV for my program but I am getting an error during the cv2.imshow command. My program is trying to process an MP4 video and crop the licence plates from the cars involved.
I am following this tutorial for this purpose, and am on 30:02 time.
Here is my code:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from sort.sort import *
import string
import easyocr

mot_tracker = Sort()
results = {}

coco_model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
license_plate_detector = YOLO('/home/pi/Desktop/license_plate_detector.pt')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/pi/Desktop/carvid.mp4')

# Initialize the OCR reader
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)

# Mapping dictionaries for character conversion
dict_char_to_int = {'O': '0',
                    'I': '1',
                    'J': '3',
                    'A': '4',
                    'G': '6',
                    'S': '5'}

dict_int_to_char = {'0': 'O',
                    '1': 'I',
                    '3': 'J',
                    '4': 'A',
                    '6': 'G',
                    '5': 'S'}


def get_car(license_plate, vehicle_track_ids):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, score, class_id = license_plate

    foundIt = False
    for j in range(len(vehicle_track_ids)):
        xcar1, ycar1, xcar2, ycar2, car_id = vehicle_track_ids[j]

        if x1 > xcar1 and y1 > ycar1 and x2 < xcar2 and y2 < ycar2:
            car_indx = j
            foundIt = True
            break

    if foundIt:
        return vehicle_track_ids[car_indx]

    return -1, -1, -1, -1, -1


ret = True
frame_nmr = -1

vehicles = [2, 3, 5, 7]

while ret:
    frame_nmr+=1
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if ret and frame_nmr < 10:
        pass
        
        detections = coco_model(frame)[0]
        detections_ = []
        
        for detection in detections.boxes.data.tolist():
            x1, y1, x2, y2, score, class_id = detection
            
            if int(class_id) in vehicles:
                detections_.append([x1,y1,x2,y2,score])
        
        track_ids = mot_tracker.update(np.asarray(detections_))
        
        license_plates = license_plate_detector(frame)[0]
        for license_plate in license_plates.boxes.data.tolist():
            x1, y1, x2, y2, score, class_id = license_plate

            xcar1, ycar1, xcar2, ycar2, carid = get_car(license_plate, track_ids)
            
            license_plate_crop = frame[int(y1):int(y2), int(x1): int(x2), :]
            
            license_plate_crop_gray = cv2.cvtColor(license_plate_crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            _, license_plate_crop_thresh = cv2.threshold(license_plate_crop_gray, 64, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
            
            cv2.imshow('original_crop', license_plate_crop)
            cv2.imshow('threshold', license_plate_crop_thresh)
            cv2.waitKey(0)


When running this, my output shows this:
Using CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.

0: 384x640 21 cars, 1 bus, 2 trucks, 483.8ms
Speed: 7.2ms preprocess, 483.8ms inference, 1.9ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)

0: 384x640 2 license_plates, 456.4ms
Speed: 5.9ms preprocess, 456.4ms inference, 0.9ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/yolotest.py", line 85, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('original_crop', license_plate_crop)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.10.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1301: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

Please help as I don't get what this is asking me todo.

Did you check https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/18 ?

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/python-opencv-imshow-error-when-running-even-when-provided-all-parameters/18459

This question is similar to: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks @Markus that git issue helped. I did do the crosspost, sry for not mentioning. All with that, this is an issue specific to OpenCV and it installation. IT IS DIFFERENT.

pip uninstall opencv-python; pip install opencv-python

fixed the problem using terminal command above

if that did anything, there must be conflicting packages that you should not have installed. if there weren't any conflicting packages, this wouldn't have done anything.

Maybe, the guy when installing opencv told me to install headless aswell, but I removed it and it works
